How can I find the actual error code on this oven?
This GE model JT3500DF6BB double wall oven sometimes stops running when in Sabbath Mode. When this happens, the display shows F ⊃ ⊃ - but not the actual fault code next to the F.
When I take it out of Sabbath Mode to try to see the error code properly on the display, that clears the error code too.
I know that for some models without a numeric keypad, it is possible to retrieve the recent fault codes by pressing +, -, and Time together, but I have not been able to find what the combination is for this model, which has a 10-key numeric keypad.
How can I find the actual fault code?

Have you tried contacting the manufacturer?

@UnhandledExcepSean GE has not been helpful.
